# insert text (menu) near navigation bar

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootsrap 4 alpha 6, and midnight.js to change the color of navigation menu toggler. I want to insert a text (MENU) next to it. Example in the Capture. For text toggler I use fontawesome.

Thanks your time and help!

the source html

```
<div class="navigation-button">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right fixed-top" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

using midnight.js, will looks like this

```
<div class="navigation-button">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right fixed-top" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; overflow: hidden; height: 40px;"><div class="midnightHeader white-menu" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; transform: translateY(110%) translateZ(0px);"><div class="midnightInner" style="position: absolute; overflow: auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; transform: translateY(-110%) translateZ(0px);">
            <span class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></span>
        </div></div><div class="midnightHeader blue-menu" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; transform: translateY(0%) translateZ(0px);"><div class="midnightInner" style="position: absolute; overflow: auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; transform: translateY(0%) translateZ(0px);">
            <span class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></span>
        </div></div></button>
    </div>
```

It works ok, only I want to add a text to it.
now it looks like:[image]

and I want

[image]

I tried

```
MENU<span class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></span>
```

it looks

[image]

Comment: have you tried just setting it to `Menu <span class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></span>`

Comment: @y0hami yes I tried, I update my question to see how it looks

Answer (score 1):

Try by adding display:inline; to your icon:

```
<span class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" style="display:inline;"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this

```
MENU<span class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" style="display:inline;"></span>
```

This will make the icon an inline element (same as the text)

Also check to see if something is restricting the width of the element, also check the parent elements for this too. This may prevent the next from displaying inline with the icon.

Comment: with flexbox I achieved what I want, thanks for your sugestion :) there was a problem

Answer (score 1):

I've manipulated some code which I answered here some time ago. Tested with my phone and it works. Its on Bootstrap. I am answering this question and drinking some wine. So, I will just close my computer soon after posting this answer. Hope is what you want.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>

</script>

<style>
.navbar {
box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
font-size: 15px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
min-height: 80px;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
position: relative;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
line-height: 80px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
color: #fff;
background-color: #b4a28f;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
left: 0;
right: auto;
}

.dropdown-menu>.active>a,
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus {
color: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
outline: 0;
background-color: #b4a28f;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.navbar-nav>li>.nav-line {
position: absolute;
bottom: -1px;
left: 0;
background-color: #3178b9;
height: 3px;
width: 0%;
}
.navbar-nav>li:hover>.nav-line {
background-color: #3178b9;
height: 3px;
width: 100%;
-webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
-o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}
.navbar-nav>li.active>.nav-line {
background-color: transparent;
}
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
.navbar-nav > li > a {
line-height: 30px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#footer {
color: #2e2e2e;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header"> 

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10 visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
                        <img class="img img-responsive" src="www/images/srs.png" alt="SRS Constructions">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-7 visible-xs">
                     <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
                         <img class="img img-responsive" src="www/images/srs.png" alt="SRS Constructions">
                     </a>                   
                </div>              

                <div style="margin-top:15px;text-align:right;" class="col-xs-3 visible-xs">
                <strong>Menu</strong>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-2">
                     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                     </button>
                 </div>

        </div>          

        </div>      

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <li class="active"><a class="main" href="#main">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    <div class="nav-line"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown" id="nav-about">
                    <a href="#about" class="dropdown-toggle main" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">The Founder</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">HSE Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Quality Policy</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="nav-line"></div>
                </li>
                <li><a class="main" href="#services">Services</a>
                    <div class="nav-line"></div>
                </li>
                <li><a class="main" href="#projects">Our Projects</a>
                    <div class="nav-line"></div>
                </li>
                <li><a class="main" href="#whyus">Why Us</a>
                    <div class="nav-line"></div>
                </li>
                <li><a class="main" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    <div class="nav-line"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanx I will try it :)

Comment: I like your non mobile menu, but I have to create for the mobile menu an offcanvas menu

Comment: Good that you've solved it as stated above. If you test that code it is mobile compatible. I tested it online before putting here

Comment: I decided to use but this code because the one you provided was not complete